# Fast inverse of positive definite matrix subtracted by its Nystrom approximation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, covariance, matrix-inverse

Assume a positive definite symmetric covariance matrix $$C_{n,n}$$ and let its Nystrom approximation be $$\hat{C}_{n,n}=C_{n,q} C^{-1}_{q,q} C_{q,n}$$ for some $q<n$

Inverting $C_{n,n}$ is of $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ complexity while inverting $\hat{C}_{n,n}$ is of $\mathcal{O}(qn^2)$ complexity. **Is there a fast way to find ?**

$$\big(C_{n,n}-\hat{C}_{n,n}\big)^{-1}$$

Comment: There's at least a way to speed up this computation in the case where $C_{n,n}^{-1}$ is already known. Is that something you'd be interested in?

Comment: Unfortunately, $C^{-1}_{n,n}$ is the unknown and most complex part of this inverse. Otherwise a woorbury formula will automatically lead to $\mathcal{O}(qn^2)$. Did you have anything in mind not woodbury related. This might be of interest